# Deriving the first term in Taylor expansion of $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying [Hadamard's factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_factorization_theorem) theorem proof from [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/12/23/246b-notes-1-zeroes-poles-and-factorisation-of-meromorphic-functions/comment-page-1/#jsf) and I have difficulties understanding one example, namely the case $f(z) = \sin(z)$.

> we see that $sin$ is of order $1$. Also, its zeroes are the integer multiples ${\pi n}$ of ${\pi}$, with ${n \in {\bf Z}}$. The Hadamard factorization theorem then tells us that we have the product expansion:
> $$\displaystyle  \sin(z) = e^{g(z)} z \prod_{n \in {\bf Z} \backslash \{0\}} E_1(\frac{z}{\pi n})$$
> for some polynomial $g$ of degree at most $1$. Writing ${E_1(\frac{z}{\pi n}) = e^{z/\pi n} (1 - \frac{z}{\pi n})}$ we can group together the ${n}$ and ${-n}$ terms in the absolutely convergent product to get
> $$\displaystyle  E_1(\frac{z}{\pi n}) E_1(\frac{z}{\pi (-n)}) = (1 - \frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2})$$
> so the Hadamard factorisation can also be written in the form:
> $$\displaystyle  \sin(z) = e^{g(z)} z \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - \frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2})$$
> Dividing by ${z}$ and taking a suitable branch ${\tilde \log}$ of the logarithm of ${\frac{\sin z}{z}}$ we see that
> $$\displaystyle  \tilde \log \frac{\sin z}{z} = g(z) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{Log} (1 - \frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2})$$
> for {z} sufficiently close to zero (removing the singularity of {\frac{\sin z}{z}} at the origin). By Taylor expansion we have
> $$\displaystyle  \frac{\sin z}{z} = 1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \dots \;\; (1)$$
> $$\displaystyle  \mathrm{Log} (1 - \frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2}) = - \frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2} + \dots \;\; (2)$$
> $$\displaystyle  \tilde \log \frac{\sin z}{z} = 2k \pi i - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \dots \;\; (3)$$
> for some integer $k$.comparing these Taylor expansions one can see that $g(z)={2\pi iz}$

I can't understand $(3)$ equation, the first term in Taylor expansion of a function around say $0$ should be it's value at $z=0$.I know that complex logarithm is a multivalued function but any branch of logarithm containing positive part of real line is equal with real logarithm and we know $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ goes to 1 as $z$ goes to zero so it's logarithm should be equal with 0.
Thanks.

Comment: When you say "any branch of logarithm containing positive part of real line is equal with real logarithm", what do you mean by "containing". Depending on what you mean, that statement is true or false. In the case of true, then we don't know whether the branch in the proof "contains" in your sense.

Comment: yeah I'm sorry it is a typo, I mean any branch of logarithm defined on domain D where D contains positive real line.

Comment: With that interpretation of "contains" the statement is false. Just add $2\pi i$ to the result of the logarithm. To (locally) fix a branch, you give a value, an output, of the logarithm. You think that in the text they are doing that, saying that the branch is that for which $\log(1)=2k\pi i$. That fixes the branch in a small enough neighborhood of $1$.

Comment: to add $2\pi i$ logarithm should be defined on whole C

Comment: I don't know what you are saying. I meant add $2\pi i$ to the output. Adding something to the output  is irrelevant to the domain.

Comment: Ahaa you're right.
Then considering this statement false, where am I missing in understanding the proof?

Comment: I don't know, you understand now the $2k\pi i$, is there anything else you missed?